# TypeScript parse generic in constructor

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a generic parameter and I want to instantiate some property based on the parameter:

```
type Foo<T> = { getValue(): T };

class NumberFoo implements Foo<number> {
  constructor(private value: number) {}
  getValue() {
    return this.value * 10;
  }
}

class StringFoo implements Foo<string> {
  constructor(private value: string) {}
  getValue() {
    return this.value + "!";
  }
}

class Bar<T extends string | number> {
  foo: Foo<T>;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this.foo =
      typeof value === "number" ? new NumberFoo(value) : new StringFoo(value);
      // ^ Type 'NumberFoo | StringFoo' is not assignable to type 'Foo<T>'.
  }
}
```

Is there some way to tell the compiler that the instantiated `foo` is guaranteed to be of type `T`, without explicitly casting `as unknown as Foo<T>`? I've tried to do this with type guards but can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT: I tried to make the example closer to my actual use case, I should have done that from the start but I was worried it would be a bit too long:

```
class Variable<T> {
  constructor(private array: T[]) {}

  fill(length: number, value: T) {
    this.array.length = length;
    this.array.fill(value);
  }

  valueAt(index: number) {
    return this.array[index];
  }

  updateAt(index: number, value: T) {
    this.array[index] = value;
  }
}

class NumericVariable extends Variable<number> {
  // Some numeric-specific methods
}

class StringVariable extends Variable<string> {
  // Some string-specific methods
}

class Reducer<T, U> {
  variable: Variable<U>;

  constructor(
    private length: number,
    private initialfn: () => U,
    private reducefn: (prev: U, next: T) => U
  ) {
    const type = typeof initialfn();

    this.variable = 
      type === "number" ? new NumericVariable([]) : new StringVariable([])

    
    this.variable.fill(length, initialfn());
  }

  clear() {
    this.variable.fill(this.length, this.initialfn());
  }

  updateAt(index: number, newValue: T) {
    const { variable, reducefn } = this;
    const updatedValue = reducefn(variable.valueAt(index), newValue);
    variable.updateAt(index, updatedValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? what is the purpose of class `Bar` and why `foo` in `Bar` is base type ? You allowed your constructor to pass `value: T` which can be string or number. So isn't that make sense to keep the `foo` as type `NumberFoo | StringFoo` ?

Comment: I would like `Bar` to be able to delegate some operations to its instance of `Foo` (i.e. call `getValue()` from `Bar`) and it to be typed properly. I don't want `foo` to be typed as `Numberfoo | Stringfoo`, because then the returntype of `getValue()` would be `string | number` but I *know* it's `T`.

Comment: Generics and control flow don't work together. `typeof value === "number"` has no effect on `T`. There are open issues asking for improvements, like [ms/TS#27808](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808). One can often refactor to avoid control flow, but your base constraint `number | string` is not a discriminated union, so I can't use the approach at [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) directly without a modification like [this](//tsplay.dev/wQLdJW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Providing the type explicitly like in the playground unfortunately doesn't really work for me, since I want the generic to be inferred from the returntype of a function: `Bar` is really something like `class Reducer<T, U> { constructor(initialfn: () => U, reducefn: (prev: U, next: T) => U ) { } }` and I want the property `foo` to depend on the returntype of `initialfn` (`U`).

Comment: I.e. I want to pick the subtype of `Foo` based on what `initialfn` returns, so that I can then delegate to it from `Bar/Reducer`

Comment: Again, unless it's represented as a discriminated union in some way, I don't think it's directly possible the way it's shown here. If you want to [edit] your example to be closer to your use case I might have another idea, but with code fragments in the comments I'm not really able to investigate.